# How to send email vis SMTP in my Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, cpanel

I am a beginner with Laravel. I am developing a Website with Laravel now and I face a difficult problem. I tried to solve this issue but I can't do. I already made login and registration logic and I need to reset the password so I am going to send email link to user to reset password.

I already set .env file like this image:

[image: screenshot]

And I got this error message:

[image: screenshot]

How can I solve this issue? (I've already hosted this website on cPanel.)

I tried several times to solve this issue.

1. I saw a article to solve this issue. Someone told me I need to change mail.xxx.com -> smtp.xxx.com so I did but it doesn't work.
2. And somebody told me this is DNS issue so I added 'extension=php_openssl.dll' in my php.ini file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sending an email from your server?

Comment: Use SMTP email service providers like mailgun, they have a free plan.

Comment: try to use [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) first.

Comment: Contact the administrator for the SMTP server, or find the documentation, and check what port they want you to use, it might be 587 or 2525, and confirm StartTLS support.

Comment: I've tried to use mailtrap but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, try using [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) and if you are using GoDaddy hosting you must consider the following.

I also faced the same problem when I could not use SMTP on GoDaddy's cPanel after a long conversation with the support team they told me it would not work on PHP 8.0^ because of some issue at their end and told me to use the PHP version 7.4 or less.

Comment: I used mailtrap but I can't solve this issue. And the most important thing is that I don't use GoDaddy's cPanel. I am using VPS.